# Solving linear programming with bounds by simplex algorithm

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I want to solve the following simplex algorithm :

Maximize $$z =x_1+x_2+2x_3-2x_4$$
Subject to 
$$ x_1+2x_3 \le 700 $$
$$ 2x_2-8x_3 \le 0 $$
$$ x_2-2x_3+2x_4 \ge 1 $$
$$ x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 10 $$
where 
$$ 0 \le x_1 \le 10$$
$$ 0 \le x_2 \le 10$$
$$ 0 \le x_3 \le 10$$
$$ 0 \le x_4 \le 10$$

I know that the standard simplex problem has following form :

Maximize $$z=c_1x_1+c_2x_2+ \ldots + c_n+x_n$$
Subject to $$a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+a_{13}x_3+\ldots+a_{1n}x_n \le b1$$
 $$a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+a_{13}x_3+\ldots+a_{1n}x_n \le b2$$
Subject to $$\ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots $$
 $$a_{m1}x_1+a_{m2}x_2+a_{m3}x_3+\ldots+a_{mn}x_n \le bm$$

where $$ x_j \ge 0 , j=1,2,3,\ldots,n$$

How can I convert my problem to standard form ? How can I solve my problems by simplex algorithm ?

## My attempt:

I have replaced $0 \le x_1 \le 10 $ by two separate constraints $ 0 \le x_1 $ and $ x_1 \le 10 $. But after that, I can't reach to optimal solution although the problem has basic feasible solution.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut There is nothing wrong with [capitalization in titles](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/capitalization/rules-for-capitalization-in-titles.html). There is no reason to change this to lower case, exctept the preposition "By".

Comment: @miracle173 The link you give mentions that the rule *"can vary according to a particular style guide"* I don't know if there is an explicit rule on MSE, however it seems to me the current practice is to *not* capitalize. But I won't argue about this if someone decides that he prefers capitals.

Comment: This is neither a simplex problem nor a simplex algorithm but a [linear programming problem or linear optimization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming). You can use the simplex algorithm to solve such problems.

Comment: Did you notice that $$x_1 \le 10$$ is an inequality of type $$a_{m1}x_1+a_{m2}x_2+a_{m3}x_3+\ldots+a_{mn}x_n \le bm$$

Answer (score 0):

Some software packages offer Linear Programming solvers. Each package has a typical formatting rules so for instance in `MATHEMATICA` we have the solver format

`LinearProgramming[c, M, b]`

in which the problem should be submitted as

$$
\max c x = c_1x_1+\cdots + c_n x_n\\
\mbox{subject to}\\
M x \ge b\\
x \ge 0
$$

with

$$
M = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 -1 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\
 0 & -2 & 8 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & -2 & 2 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right), b = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 -700 \\
 0 \\
 1 \\
 10 \\
 -10 \\
 -10 \\
 -10 \\
 -10 \\
 -10 \\
\end{array}
\right), c = (1,1,2,-2)
$$

and the result is

$$
x_0 = (0,0,0,10)
$$

NOTE

The equality

$$
x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 10
$$

is handled as

$$
x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 \ge 10\\
x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 \le 10
$$